# Swift compilation does not use the precompile headers

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

The problem was the swift code was getting compiled every time even with no change in the code.

Trying to figure out why precompile bridging header is not happening in my old app, whereas it happens in any new app.

I am using the latest Xcode 9.2 version.

SWIFT_PRECOMPILE_BRIDGING_HEADER - basically this doesn't seem to work even though its on in build settings.

[image]

Comment: Are you making changes to a storyboard? Or are you just running, stopping, and running and it compiles every time?

Comment: Nope i don't have any change Honestly nothing ! Just stopping after it compiles and running it again

Answer (score 0):

OK precompile bridging header only precompiles the header itself. It does not precompile the swift code. The apps need both obj-c and swift and a bridging header in order for that to run. Does the old project have this?

Comment: Yeah it has it Jared

Comment: Sorry couldnt comment before because im shy two rep. Are you able to post the build setting about precompile for both of them